# zend form with jquery mobile and recaptcha

Tags: php, zend-framework, jquery-mobile, recaptcha

I've got a problem with trying to implement reCaptcha into zend form in jquery mobile application. When jquery mobile is disabled then everything is alright but I need to use it but then I can only see label from recaptcha + validation message.

```
$recaptcha = new Zend_Service_ReCaptcha(
    '644443tQSAA4444444444444444444WNm6',
    '6L44443444444444444444444EmA_4448');

$captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('challenge2',
    array(
        'captcha'        => 'ReCaptcha',
        'captchaOptions' => array(
            'captcha' => 'ReCaptcha', 
            'service' => $recaptcha
        )
    )
);

$captcha->setLabel('hello');        
$captcha->setErrorMessages(array( 'Please retape above words correctly'));
$this->addElement($captcha);
```

I was trying to `$captcha->setAttrib('data-role', 'none')` but didn't help.
How to show reCaptcha on jQuery Mobile using Zend Framework?

Comment: Did you find solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Here it has information on how this could be handled https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display?hl=en#AJAX

What I did, is added this script to the layout:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
```

Then, on the page which has captcha, I have the following code:

```
$('[data-role=page]').on('pagebeforeshow', function (event, ui) {
    if ($('#recaptcha_widget_div').length<1) { //if it was not loaded earlier
        Recaptcha.create("<your key>", 'captcha-element', {
            lang : 'en',
            tabindex: 1,
            theme: "clean",
            callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
        });
    }
}
```

"captcha-element" is id of the div which wraps my captcha element.